# Include number of pages (page count) of a reference in Bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Is there a way to get the length (number of pages) of a paper and have it be listed in my references. For example, Paper title, author, number of pages.

A final result would be something like:

References
[1] Author Name, Paper Name, Conference, Year, 20 Pages.
[1] Author Name, Paper Name, Conference, Year, 15 Pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `biblatex`. It defines a `pagetotal` field. For articles, you can use the `addendum` field, which may contain whatever you want and is printed at the end of the reference.

Comment: `bibtex` does not have such an option?